# How can I debug my program to reverse a word?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, char

I am trying to write a program that would reverse the word.

**My code:**

```
public class reverseword

{
static String s = "AHAMED";
static char[] c = s.toCharArray();
static char[] reverse = new char[c.length];

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < c.length - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = reverse.length - 1; j >=0 ; j = j -1)
        {
            reverse[j] = c[i];
        }
    }
    String r = String.valueOf(reverse);
    System.out.println(r);
}
}
```

**Output:**

```
EEEEE
```

**Expected Output:**

```
DEMAHA
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Don't use nested for loops. Use a **single** for loop.

Comment: Uh, it sure looks to me like he did, @Robert.

Answer (score 1):

Your loops should be like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < c.length - 1;)
        for(int j = reverse.length - 1; j >=0 ; j--,i++)
            reverse[j] = c[i];
```

which can be enhanced further by using one loop:

```
for (int i=0, j=(reverse.length - 1); i < (c.length - 1) || j >= 0; j--, i++)
        reverse[i] = c[j];
```

However, this is not the ideal way to reverse a String.

Comment: You only need to go halfway to reverse a string, by the way.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed it's using two different arrays. The halfway trick works with swapping characters in *one* array.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is wrong:

```
i < c.length - 1
```

You never get last symbol. Use either

```
i < c.length
```

or

```
i <= c.length - 1
```

And try to "execute" internal loop in your mind - it'll get just what you've written - take symbol from **c**, then set it to all places of **reverse**. It makes that for all symbols of **c** (except last, see previous error) - so only last attempt stored in **reverse**.
You should eliminate internal loop and use construction like

```
reverse[(c.length-1)-i] = c[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second array - a `StringBuilder` is better. I'm not sitting in front of an IDE, but try something like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = originalString.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    sb.append(originalString[i]);
```

If you really want two arrays, you still only need a single loop. I haven't tested it, but try something like this:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = originalString.Length - 1; i >= 0; i---) {
       array[j] = originalString[i];
     j++;
}
```

Again, I'm not at an IDE, so this may require slight tweaking.